# Multiple logistic regression odds ratio on multiply imputed data in R

Tags: r, odds-ratio, multiple-imputation, pooling, mice

I am running a hierarchical logistic regression analysis using multiply imputed data in R (using the mice and miceafter packages). I am unable to get the odds ratio and 95% CI per variable adjusted for all other variables.

Here is what I have done so far:

`Model1 <- with(imp, glm(complaints ~ Sex + Age + Education, family = binomial(link = 'logit')))`

`pool.model1 <- summary(pool(Model1), conf.int = TRUE, exponentiate = TRUE)`

Now, I manage to get odds ratios, but only separately per combination of predictor and dependent variable:

`long <- mice::complete(imp, "long", include = TRUE)`

`imp_data <- df2milist(long, impvar=".imp")`

`ra <- with(imp_data, expr=odds_ratio(complaints ~ Sex))`

`OR <- pool_odds_ratio(ra)`

If I add another predictor I get the following error:

> *Error in odds_ratio(complaints ~ Sex + Age) :
> Include single independent variable only or use function psfmi_lr*

The problem is that I of course want the odds ratios (and 95% CI) while considering the influence of the other variables.

Is it statistically correct to compute the:

1. pooled odds ratio by taking the exponential function of the pooled regression coefficient
2. pooled 95% CI by taking the pooled regression coefficient +/- 1.96 * pooled SE?

Comment: "Now, I manage to get odds ratios, but only separately per combination of predictor and dependent variable"---What do you mean by this statement? So far I don't see any issue with what you did in the first code chunk but I don't know what you are trying to do with the rest.

Comment: The issue is that I either get an OR (and CI) that only has one predictor in the model or I get an OR (CI) with all predictors but then not pooled and instead separately per imputed dataset. So I am wondering whether there is a function in R that will give me the pooled OR for a model with all predictors or whether I can calculate it somehow.